# The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in "atg.project" was unable to instantiate class

Tags: eclipse, atg

Hi I am getting below error while creating an ATG module in Eclipse. I am using eclipseNeon (eclipse-jee-neon-M1-win32-x86_64), JDK 1.8.60, ATG11.2. I have already tried following solutions:

1. set up the ATG preferences to the root directory (C:\ATG\ATG11.2)via Windows->Preference->ATG Preference.
2. I have added up the ATGUpdateSite jar in Eclipse plugin folder
3. I have changed the perspective of Eclipse to ATG perspective.

   ```
   Error:  The selected wizard could not be started.
   Plug-in "atg.project" was unable to instantiate class "atg.eclipse.project.wizard.ProjectWizard".
   atg/applauncher/AppLauncherExceptionThe selected wizard could not be started.
   ```

Comment: Eclipse Neon is now at Milestone 5, if you are going to use code that is still in development you need to keep up to date on the Milestones. ATG may not have been tested with Neon yet. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: I tried using Eclipse Mars also, same issue with that too. The error log in .log file is as below: !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-22 10:26:20.352
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate atg.eclipse.framework.extension.AppUtilsProxy
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: atg.applauncher.AppUtils
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: So you need to find out where the `atg.applauncher.AppUtils` class is supposed to be because it is currently missing.

Comment: According to the Oracle Commerce Supported Environments document for 11.2 the Development Plugin for Eclipse is only supported for Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

Comment: Yes, It worked . Thanks

Comment: Hi Varsha. How it worked for you? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to Bit version mismatch. Make sure that your bit versions of Oracle ATG and Eclipse are same.